# Outlook 2013: All day event not visible in folder pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have an all day event on 23th of October (i can see it if I select that day in the folder pane), but it is not shown (the day is not in bold like for other events, like on days 8, 12, 15, 17...) in the folder pane.

Is this a bug? Can I change some option to have days with all day events marked?

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook will not show the date in the Folder Pane as bold with an event that is shown as **Free**. Change your all-day event from **Free** to **Busy**.

[image: Free-to-busy event change]

Source: [How To Bold Dates In Small Calendar On Navigation Pane In Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4191-outlook-calendar-bold-dates.html)